# How to load image every 40milisecond

Tags: php

I write a source php to load images every 1 second by the way i refresh webpage every 1 second. But now i would like to load it faster to create images sequence like a video. I would like to load image every 40 milisecond
This is my php sourcecode to load image every 1second:

```
<?php
header("Refresh: 0.04; URL=$url1");
if(!empty($_REQUEST['image'])) {
    $base=$_REQUEST['image'];
    $binary=base64_decode($base);
    $file = fopen('uploaded_image.jpg', 'wb');
    fwrite($file, $binary);
    fclose($file);
}
echo "<img src='uploaded_image.jpg'/> ";
?>
```

Please help me to solve it. I searched in internet 1 month but I can't find anything to solve my problem
Thank you so much

Comment: This is a very bad way to create a video as the image will possibly never fully load.

Comment: I don't think `header` allows milliseconds. Try `setTimeout` in javascript. But its a bad practice though!

Comment: @Thamilan **setTimeout** is javascript.

Comment: @Maurice Yes I know, javascript can be embedded inside PHP.

Comment: As @Jerodev suggest to you, that is not the best way to achieve it. How about to check some ways in javascript to build a carrousel o something similar?

Comment: I think this is very bad way too. Do you have another way to load image faster like a video

Comment: Hello, somebody help me